# How to specify which GPU to use when running tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, gpu

We have a DGX-1 in Lab.

I see many tasks are running on different GPU.

For MLperf docker application, I can use NV_GPU=x to assign which GPU to use.

However, I have a python Keras/TensorFlow code, I used this same way, the loading doesn't go to the specified GPU.

Comment: Did you try setting the GPU using CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES??

Comment: No, I don't know this control, I tried it, it works, thanks!

Comment: Can you upload your code?

Comment: I modified from https://github.com/keon/deep-q-learning/blob/master/dqn.py

Comment: I am writing it as an answer so that it might help others who might see this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to specify the GPU to be used by your model:

```
import os 
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = 0,1  #Will assign GPUs 0 and 1 to the model
```